# Show $f_n$ tends to $0$ pointwise

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm having a little trouble with this question,

Define the functions $f_n : [0,1]$ to real numbers by $f_n(x) = n^p \; x \; e^{-n^qx}$ where $p$ and $q$ are greater than $0$.

I need to show $f_n$ tends to $0$ pointwise on $[0,1]$ as $n$ tends to infinity, therefore I need to show the limit of $f_n(x)$ as $n$ tends to infinity is $0$.

I'm having a bit of trouble getting started. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Let put, for $p>0,q>0,n>0$ and $0\leq x \leq 1$,

$$f_n(x)=xn^pe^{-xn^q}=xg_n(x).$$

$x=0 \implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(0)=0$

assume $x\in (0,1]$.

we have

$$ln(g_n(x))=n^q(p\frac{ln(n)}{n^q}-x).$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}ln(g_n(x))=$$

$$+\infty(0-x)=
-\infty$$ since $x>0$ and near $+\infty$, the polynomial is faster than logarithm.

thus

$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=0$.

The zeo function is the pointwise limit of the  sequence of functions $(f_n)$  at$[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're familiar with Taylor expansions. Note that the Taylor expansion of $e^y$ is given by:
$$e^y = 1+y+\frac{y^2}{2!}+\frac{y^3}{3!}+\cdots = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{y^k}{k!}$$
Now if $y>0$, then every term in this expansion is also greater than 0. Thus we can deduce the following inequality:
$$\forall k \in \mathbb{N}:\forall y>0: e^y > \frac{y^k}{k!}$$
Note that we can rewrite the inequality to $\frac{1}{e^y} < k! \frac{1}{y^k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y>0$. Given that $n^q x>0$, we deduce the following for $x \in (0,1]$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$f_n(x) = n^px e^{-n^qx} = n^px\frac{1}{e^{n^qx}} < n^p x  \frac{k!}{(n^q x)^k} = k! \;n^{p-kq} x^{1-k}$$
Choose a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $qk>p$, and thus $p-qk<0$. In that case $n^{p-qk}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Note that $f_n$ is positive for every $n$. We find $\forall x \in (0,1]$:
$$0 \leq f_n(x) <k! \;n^{p-kq} x^{1-k} \to 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad f_n(x) \to 0$$
Considering that $f_n(0)=0$ for every $n$, we conclude that $f_n \to 0$ pointwise. $\Box$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $e^x $ grows faster than $x^a.$ for given $p,q$ you can find $n$, after which the function starts decreasing.